# An user is able to see the public report folder without the permission "View Reports in Public Folders" in his profile

Tags: reporting, profile, permission-sets

Hello,

In my Salesforce, an user is able to see the "Public Reports" folder without the permission "View Reports in Public Folders" in his profile.

I mean, he is able to see reports in the "Public Reports" folder.

In his profile, the permission "View Reports in Public Folders" is unchecked but "Run Reports" is checked, nothing else ("View all Data" is unchecked).

The user doesn't have any permission set assigned to him.

Do you know how it is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Unfiled Public Reports Folder` is accessible by all users and is generally used as a placeholder until a report can be moved to a custom report folder.

The `Unfiled Public Reports Folder` contains shared custom reports created by your Administrator, but not filed into a Custom Report Folder.

This folder is generally used as a placeholder folder for new reports until a Custom Report Folder has been created. Once the new folders are created, you can move your reports to different folders.

> In Lightning, this folder is called Public Reports.

Refer the help [article](https://Unfiled%20Public%20Reports%20Folder%20Overview)